# Distinct count a field that has been sorted by territory from another source

Tags: filter, count, crystal-reports, distinct

I am trying to find a way to get a distinct count on a field that is being filtered by a territory without using grouping because of the fact that I need to then pass this value over to another report. The easiest way would be something like this:

```
distinctcount({Comm_Link.CmLi_Comm_CompanyId}) if  {Company.Comp_Territory}='Atlanta'
```

But for obvious reasons that won't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is a running total. Right click on `{Comm_Link.CmLi_Comm_CompanyId}` insert `running total`, type of summary will be `distinct count` and on `evaluate` where says `Use a formula` type your condition `{Company.Comp_Territory}="Atlanta"`

Answer (score 0):

your formula and approach is wrong.. I doubt whether your formula compiled with out any errors...

first create the value and then find the `distinct count`

```
 if  {Company.Comp_Territory}='Atlanta'
Then {Comm_Link.CmLi_Comm_CompanyId}
```

Now in footer write or you can get it by right click on the filed.

```
distinctcount({Comm_Link.CmLi_Comm_CompanyId})
```